# Test smart tv app on Philips TV

Tags: javascript, smart-tv, smart-tv-alliance

The Samsung Smart TV's have got a developer account, with the developer account you can download applications from your computer to your tv for stand alone use or to test them.

I need to do tha same thing, but in a Philips smart TV. Have these TVs a developer built in account? Do I need to use a pen drive for DDR? How can I test a js web application on Philips plataform?

Comment: I've tryied to access my app from the tv's browser. It is possible and it works. However, in this scenario, the videos are played by the browser video render engine, not the tv video engine, so my videos aren't played.

Comment: Is your device Android based or it is earlier NETTV version?

Comment: No, it's an earlier TV, FL600 family, from year 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TV Browser to test your apps. If your app pages served with correct CE-HTML Content-Type, then browser will not display controls and focus outline.

We test all our apps that way. CE-HTML video playback works same way in TV Browser and in Gallery-installed apps.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, it's a quite interesting approach. The content type tag I use is:

    `code` <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/ce-html+xml;charset=UTF-8" /> 

I have made no modifications to the apache config files. When I execute the ce-html and play the video, nothing happens. I assume is because it runs the TV browser instead of the real smart hub. Am I right? The whole application works fine on LG tv.

Comment: If you don't see yellow outline on focused elements, that means, that content-type is correct.
Do you use TV Alliance SDK or LG SDK? Because Philips devices might require different API for video playback. Check [documentation](http://www.yourappontv.com/documentation/app-how-tos/technical#link5) (requires registration)

Comment: Ok, I left my app aside and try a philips basic example page with a video. I used the TV browser and it works, so the problem should be on my code, probably as it was refered on some video API methods. Thanks a lot Ivan!!

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is via the Philips MiniPortal application.

You have to supply them with your MAC address and the hosted URLs of the apps you wish to test.  After that, you'll be given a PIN code that allows you to test your app in the proper environment.

If you have a Partner contact at Philips, you can contact them directly to activate it, otherwise you might be able to request it via the developer forum at https://www.yourappontv.com/home

Please note that this app might only be available to those with Partner status.